# "File cannot be accessed" 1004 Export worksheets error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I couldn't solve the error. I searched SO but couldn't find the solution. The code works 98%. Just 2% needed to be solved.

Userform :
[image]

On click of Browse button, "Select a Folder" dialog box opens. The selected folder path is displayed in the textbox.

Code :

```
Dim sItem As String

Private Sub browse_Button_Click()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim strPath As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
showFilePath.Text = sItem
End Sub

Private Sub cancel_button_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub export_button_Click()
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = sItem & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
        If xlsx = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsm = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xls = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Unload Me
        ElseIf xlsb = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            Unload Me
        ElseIf csv = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
            Unload Me
        ElseIf txt = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4158
            Unload Me
        ElseIf html = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".html": FileFormatNum = 44
            Unload Me
        ElseIf prn = True Then
            FileExtStr = ".prn": FileFormatNum = 36
            Unload Me
        End If
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum   '<---ERROR HERE
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I get an error at the end, after selecting a folder and also the format to export the worksheet.

Error:
[image]

NOTE: The excel file is saved in E:/VBA/AJD/Export Worksheets.xlsm. And the worksheets are to be exported in other location(user selects a folder). Hence the excel file which runs the code and the export folder is in different location.

The path:

[image]

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but have you checked all the possible issues that are listed in the error pop-up?

Comment: Yeah I did. Specified folder I selected was E: drive. There are 3 folders inside E: drive. File name doest not contain any of those special characters. And file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters. Its just E:/

Comment: Are the locations local on your PC or is it a shared location somewhere?

Comment: @Vityata the locations in my local PC. not shared.

Comment: @Vityata the error its giving me is in this line `Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum`

Comment: @AmanDevrath - Can you write `MsgBox xFile` on the line before the error and share what do you get in the cases, when there is an erorr?

Comment: Tip: Export-Button_Click has empty sItem variable when showFilePath is empty. So include a check; for example: If Dir(ShowFilePath.Text) = "" then sItem = showFilePath.Text, Else..... Exit sub for example. It will check if your folder is valid. Also, I'm not sure about this but you try to include a "backslash" when the rest in your path includes "slash", in your Foldername.

Comment: Also can you please include the result of: debug.print xFile, just before the line that errors out?

Comment: @Vityata this is what I got with `Msgbox xFile`     https://ibb.co/ezJ7x8

Comment: @JvdV Thanx for the tip. I'll include it after the error is solved(hopefully) :P Here you go... https://ibb.co/ezJ7x8 for the `Msgbox xFIle`

Comment: @AmanDevrath - the error seems to be because of the two `\\\` in path, I guess.

Comment: That's correct. I got your error on the double backslash. It should be a single backslash. @Vityata, sorry for the double msgbox/debug.print. I haven't read your suggestions properly.

Comment: Got it.. the code should be `FolderName = sItem & xWb.Name & " " & DateString`

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. @Vityata

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help @JvdV

Comment: @AmanDevrath, When you use 'Browse' and select an actual folder, your code would be correct. As it would for example get the result: "E:\ExampleFolder". But when you just select E, the result would be "E:\". In the last case you don't want to include the extra "\". You'll have to include a check if the most far right character is a backslash and buils xFile accordingly.

Comment: You are right @JvdV . This doesnt work when I select a folder, it works only when I select a drive like E:/ or F:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution, when you are getting an error in VBA is to read carefully the error message box. In this case, the first suggestion is the correct one - "Make sure the specified folder exists".

The easiest way to check, whether the folder exists is to see the path. Possible solution:

```
MsgBox xFile
```

Which prints the folder and lets you debug from then on. Usually the error is visible, as in this case, where two `\\` are present:

[image]

**Edit:**

In this case OP could check first if showFilePath (Browse) has been used correctly:

```
If Dir(showFilePath.Text) = "" Then
    sItem = showFilePath.Text
Else
    MsgBox "No folder selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Second, OP could check which of the following situations applies:

```
If Right(sItem, 1) = "\" Then 'Backslash is yet present
    FolderName = sItem & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
Else
    FolderName = sItem & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString 'Add a Backslash
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. But this correction in code only works if drive is selected, not if a folder is selected.

Comment: @Vityata, I have included some pieces of code for OP to avoid these error in the future. Hopefully that's ok with you.